# flutter - async function always returns null, while it is not null

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using Bloc architect for my project. I am trying to use a function from my Bloc file in the Ui of my app, and send a form to server and use the response. but when I make the call it returns null. while the response is not null in other parts of my app(i.e repo etc.) here is the code of my Ui:

```
MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      minWidth: screenAwareSize(500, context),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _submitForm(authBloc, user, pass);
                      },
 void _submitForm(AuthBloc authBloc, String user, String pass) async {
    formKey.currentState.save();
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      var response = await authBloc.login(user, pass);
//when I print(response) it shows null


    }
  }
```

here is my bloc class:

```
class AuthBloc extends MainBloc {
  final Repo _repo = Repo();
  PublishSubject<Future<UserModel>> _authController = new PublishSubject<Future<UserModel>>();
  Observable<Future<UserModel>> get auth => _authController.stream;
  login(String user, String pass) async {

    Future<UserModel> item = await _repo.login(user, pass);
    _authController.sink.add(item);
  }

  dispose() {
    _authController.close();
  }
}

AuthBloc authBloc = new AuthBloc();
```

and here is my API class:

```
class API{
 Future<UserModel> login(String user, String pass) async {
    var response =
        await client.get(base_url + "login.php?user=${user}&pass=${pass}");
    return UserModel.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
  }}
```

here is my repo class:

```
 class Repo {
    final API api = new API();
  login(String user, String pass) async => await api.login(user, pass);}
```

Comment: Use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `login(String user, String pass)` does not seems to return anything. By default, it will return `Future<void>`. That's why your response is null.

The easiest way to fix this is to return item in your login function as follow.

```dart
    Future<UserModel> login(String user, String pass) async {
    return _repo.login(user, pass);
  }
```

Although, this might work. I don't think this is the proper of using Bloc architecture in the Rx way.

You may consider using `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` in your view.
And convert your `auth` to type of `Future<UserModel>`. And make your view subscribe to changes in `AuthBloc`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am newbie in the bloc pattern, could you please show me by code how can I do the changes according to the last line of your answer?