# flutter - unable to send API request with FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make an API call using FutureBuilder in flutter but it seems like the request is not sent because I do not see the response printing. here is my future builder:

```
FutureBuilder(
future: authBloc.login(user, pass),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshotItem) {
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshotItem.data[0];
 print(data['response']);
 if (data.containsKey('id')) {
 saveId(data['id']);
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
 MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
 return MainPage();
 }));
 }
 if (data.containsKey("response")) {
 if (data['response'] == false) {
 showDialog(
 context: context,
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
 return AlertDialog(
 title: Text('An Error Has Occurred'),
 content: Text(
 'Please Make Sure That You Are Entering Valid UserName And Password'),
  actions: <Widget>[
  FlatButton(
  child: Text("OK"),
  onPressed: () =>
  Navigator.of(context).pop(),
  )
   ],
    );
      });
       }
     }
    },
   );
```

the `authBloc.login(user, pass),` part is login function in another file that makes the API call and I thought it is not necessary to include that file here.

Comment: I think the problem is that you build the ```Future``` in the build method, the future has to be obtained before the ```build``` method is called.

Comment: thanks. how should I do that? I am pretty new to flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't see the rest of your code, I think what you are trying to achieve should be done with an method and not a widget. When the user presses submit, call a function that basically contains what you wrote on that builder.

Calling navigator from within the builder is a bad idea. Any builder is expected to be called multiple times and in your case will lead to unexpected behaviour, that might be what you are seeing

Comment: I have tried that too, and this was the result:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444966/flutter-async-function-always-returns-null-while-it-is-not-null/55448366#55448366

Comment: What you have there is more complicated. What i'm saying is just a simple direct function call to your api and wait for the result, and then call navigator to home page or just setState to error.